How to convert the following json object into to a new JSON object in c#
Json Data in present format: currently I am getting data from a database in the following format which I am storing in a DataTable.
Database format
var data1 =
[{"TheatreName":"AMEA","Country":"CANADA","Riskcount":50},{"TheatreName":"AMEA","Country":"UK","Riskcount":30},{"TheatreName":"AMER","Country":"Japan","Riskcount":80},{"TheatreName":"AMER","Country":"US","Riskcount":90},{"TheatreName":"APAC","Country":"Bangladesh","Riskcount":4},{"TheatreName":"APAC","Country":"Hong Kong","Riskcount":12},{"TheatreName":"APAC","Country":"India","Riskcount":126}]
I want to convert it into a JSON object in the following format.
var data =
{
 "APAC": {
   "Bangladesh": 30,
   "Hong Kong": 40,
    "India":50
  
 },
 "AMEA": {
   "UK": 30,
   "CANADA": 50
 },
 "AMER": {    
   "Japan": 80,
"US": 90
 }
}


This question is similar to: Convert datatable to JSON in C#. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The database may be able to supply the data in JSON format directly, if that is the only reason for creating a datatable.

If you already have class for above properties , so it already in list of item you need to write Linq query group by TheatreName
var groupedData = oldjson.GroupBy(t => t.TheatreName);

groupedData serialize/convert the object

Using arrow function in your data apply this condition resultdata similer data1.
 var chartData = [];
 var resultData =
[{"TheatreName":"AMEA","Country":"CANADA","Riskcount":50},{"TheatreName":"AMEA","Country":"UK","Riskcount":30},{"TheatreName":"AMER","Country":"Japan","Riskcount":80},{"TheatreName":"AMER","Country":"US","Riskcount":90},{"TheatreName":"APAC","Country":"Bangladesh","Riskcount":4},{"TheatreName":"APAC","Country":"Hong Kong","Riskcount":12},{"TheatreName":"APAC","Country":"India","Riskcount":126}]

Apply this function
    var data ={};
resultData.forEach(item=>{
if(!data[item.TheatreName]){
data[item.TheatreName]={};
}
data[item.TheatreName][item.Country]=item.Riskcount;
});

